# Chart.JS issue on mobile devices (Wordpress Page)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, charts, chart.js

I created a chart that grabs certain numbers by element id, when using the code in a wordpress page it works fine on desktops but the chart doesn't show up on mobile devices

when i tested it locally from HTML file it was fine on both mobile and desktop my guess it's a compatibility issue between the code i used and wordpress

here is the code i used

```
    <p id="rollthedice">
      20
    </p>

    <canvas id="myChart" style="position: relative; height:60vh; width:90vw"></canvas>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var numDice = parseInt(document.getElementById("rollthedice").textContent);
    </script>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 24;
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['dice 1', 'dice 2', 'dice 3', 'dice 4'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'result',
            data: [numDice, 90, 70, 100, 50, 40],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                  stepSize: 10
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>
```